# Как получить сведенья об изменение в таблицы с помощью psycopg2 в python

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

У меня есть база данных в postgreSQL,а в ней таблица и хочу получить уведомление, если в ней произошли изменения (например: обновились данные в строке или добавилась новая строка).Я знаю, что в postgreSQL есть
LISTEN / notify (), но не понимаю, как с ними работают( и они в целом работают тоже не понимаю), что в самом postgreSQL, то и в питоне :c
Подскажите, люди добрые

Вот так подключаюсь к БД

```
class PostgreSQL_BD:  # Класс "БД"
    def __init__(self):
        self.connection = None  # Соединение
        self.cursor = None      # Курсор
    # Установка соединения с БД
    def create_connection(self, db_name, db_user, db_password, db_host, db_port):
        self.connection = None
        try:
            self.connection = psycopg2.connect(
                database=db_name,
                user=db_user,
                password=db_password,
                host=db_host,
                port=db_port,
            )
            self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
            return True
        except OperationalError as e:
            print(f"The error '{e}' occurred")
            return False
    # Исполнение запроса
    def execute(self, query):
        try:
            self.cursor.execute(query)
            self.connection.commit()
            return True
        except OperationalError as e:
            print(f"The error '{e}' occurred")
            return False
```

Comment: Попробуйте начать отсюда: https://pypi.org/project/pgnotify/